# Get Count Attribute in AWS Appsync

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I found out there is "scannedCount" and "count" in dynamodb, I can get scannedCount in Appsync but not Count

```
query getUsers{
     listUsers(filter:{gender:{eq:'m'} limit:10){
       items{
         name
       }
       nextToken
       count
       Count
       scannedCount
     }
}
```

I have this as a result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listUsers": {
      "items": [
        {"name": "jenny"},
        {"name": "alice"},
        {"name": "bella"},
        {"name": "april"}
      ],
      "nextToken": null,
      "count": null,
      "Count": null,
      "scannedCount": 4,
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get count attribute in appsync ?

Thanks a lot
Rodolphe

Answer (score 0):

You do have access to the "scannedCount" but not the "count" and there is currently no way to access it through AppSync. I will record this as a feature request.